# how to get access Token from fb login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Here i have some code for fb login.And i use one custom button for login Form this code i can get the id, name, email id and all.But i need to get the accesstoken when one user login with fb.How can i get that.

```
 @IBAction func loginBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        })    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

i tried this :

```
var fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
```

But i got fatel error crash report. And also i don't know how to keep it inside my function, where i am getting name, email id, so on.

Comment: What is the error crash report do you have?

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
`

Comment: what i need is i need to pass emailid, access token when user login with fb. then only they can enter in to my app and see the data available. So how can i get the accessToken same like id,emalid, name, last name.....Like that how can i get the accessToken??